# Conditional hightlighting based on a 'set' amount above the values in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

My Excel formula skills are pretty basic and even worse when it comes to conditional formatting. Essentially the following image shows my mileage report which calculates miles taken for each route that we have.

[image: Excel Capture of Mileage Report]

What I would like it to do is highlight values in the `G` column if they are over 3 miles of the expected run mileage (the table on the right hand side).

This requires me to, first of all, look up the value of `D3` in order to match this in the table on the right (`I3`) to find the run for this line, then to find the required run amount (`J3`) if the two cells match, and to only highlight if the value of the cell is 3 miles over the value in `J3`.

It's possible I am just coming up with a really long winded way of doing this and have overlooked something, but if anyone could come up with something I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected, it is quite simple. Select the range `G3:G14` and enter the following for the conditional formatting formula:

```
=G3>VLOOKUP(D3,I:J,2,FALSE)+3
```

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

See [this post](//superuser.com/a/1330857) for a better understanding of how to write conditional formatting formulas.

Answer (score -1):

What you need for this is a conditional formatting rule based on a formula.

[image: New Formatting Rule window with "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" selected.]

I remember finding this particular aspect of conditional formatting to be very confusing in the past because Excel provides no explanation that I could find at the time, and there's no feedback in the New Formatting Rule window to let you know if you're going to get the result you want.

As such, here's some things to remember when writing a conditional formatting formula:

- The formula should be written from the perspective of the first cell you want to format

  - Other cells will be formatted as if this formula had been copied from the first cell and pasted into them.
    If you don't want a particular row or column reference in your formula to change, prepend it with a `$` (e.g. `D3`, when copied from cell G3 to G4 will now reference `D4`, but if you wanted to always reference the exact cell "D3" you'd write it as `$D$3`, locking it to that exact row and that exact column, or if you only wanted to lock it to that row but let the column float, it should be `D$3`)
- Conditional Formatting is applied if the formula evaluates to `TRUE` and is not if it evaluates to `FALSE`.
- If you need feedback, write your formula in a cell and see what result you get, then copy/paste that formula to the formula input on the "New Formatting Rule" dialog.

Also, as a side-note, it's [recommended](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446D94AF-663B-451D-8251-369D5E3864CB#bmarray_form) to use `VLOOKUP` as opposed to `LOOKUP` for this use-case.

The formula for this specific case is this `=G3>3+VLOOKUP(D3,I:J,2)`, but hopefully the above tips will help to demystify conditional formatting based on a formula so that it's easier to write your own in the future.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least tell me why.